# Get value from javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have to get id from table data (SQL).

Below is a form, in which I have to get proper id. But in JavaScript I don't get id from more data. I am getting only same data id from table.

please tell me how to get id from table in SQL

HTML Form:

```
 <div>
     <textarea name="comment" id="comment1" class="form-control comment" rows="3" placeholder="Leave comment"></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" id="cid1" value="<?php  echo $ws1['forum_id']; ?>">
 </div>
 <input class="btn btn btn-noc" type="submit" value="Submit" id="addressSearch" href="#myModalnew" role="button" data-toggle="modal"> 

<form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">User name</label>
        <div class="controls">

          <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User name">
           <p id="username_error" class="validation"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email id</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email id">
           <p id="email_error" class="validation"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Mobile no</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Mobile no">
           <p id="phone_error" class="validation"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">

          <input type="button" class="btn btn-nocone" value="Submit" onClick="xxx()">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
 function xxx() {
    regexp=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    regexp1=/^\d{10}$/;

    function showError(id, msg) {
        if (msg != "") {
           document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '*' + msg;
        }
        else {
           document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = msg;
        }
    }

    err = '';
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    if (username == "" || username == null) {
        showError('username_error', 'Please Fill Name');
        err = 1;
    } else {
        showError('username_error', '');
    }

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (!regexp.test(email)) {
       showError('email_error', 'Please Fill valid Email address.');
       err = 2;
    } else {
       showError('email_error', '');
    }

    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

    if (!regexp1.test(phone)) {
        showError('phone_error', 'Please Fill valid Phone Number.');
        err = 3;
    } else {
        showError('phone_error', '');
    }

    if(err!=''){
        return false
    }
    else {

        cmnt = document.getElementById('comment').value;
        usr = document.getElementById('username').value;
        emil = document.getElementById('email').value;
        phn = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        fid = document.getElementById('cid').value;


        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url:'submit_form/insert_comment.php',
           dataType: "html",
           cache: false,
           async: false,
           data: {
              comment: cmnt,
              username: usr,
              email:emil,
              phone:phn,
              id: fid
          }
       });
    }
    showError('error','Your comment have been sent sucessfully');   
    $("#please").click();
 }
```

Comment: You're free to format your code any way you like for yourself, but when asking other people for help, please have the courtesy to format the code in some reasonable, consistent way. Perhaps use http://jsbeautifier.org or similar.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Put it in the question so it's readable.

Comment: Vidhipriya, your code is not a complete one. Put your html part also in you question and clearly mention what you actually needed.

Comment: Please post the SQL you are using to fetch the id from sql? your logic code will also be needed

Comment: Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2dbxz2r/15/). Hope it helps :-)

Comment: nope dear Im getting only one value for all cid data

Comment: The hidden field stores a single value which is from $ws1['forum_id']; What you really needed?\

Comment: yes I want to get a forum_id from table but i'm getting only first data from table for each and every values

Comment: Please provide your code that fetching the table data 'forum_id'. You need to get all the ids from table as list and set the list as value of your hidden value. Then loop through the list items with the ajax request insert_comment.

Comment: Please check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2dbxz2r/17/)

Comment: No this is putting only value='2'.

Comment: Please try this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2dbxz2r/22/) Let me know if you need to update different data for comment, name, email, phone, if so you need to add select box with values as forum_ids. I think u get ma point?\